# Namespace SPSite , SPWeb could not be found

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using [sharpdevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) to write a program which would add items to a pre-existing list on a SharePoint website .

This is my code :

```
        using System.IO;
        using Microsoft.SharePoint;
        using System;


        namespace Sampl22.cs
        {
            class Program
            {
                public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://community.intranet/Lists/AllItems.aspx"))
                      {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())                  
                             {
                                SPList list = web.Lists["Sample Forms Data"];
                                SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                                item["FormName"] = "New Form";
                                item["Data"] = "Description of Task";
                                 item.Update();
                             }
                      }
                }
            }
        }
```

and the errors that i am getting are :

> The type or namespace name 'SPSite' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>  The
>   type or namespace name 'SPList' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>  The type or
>   namespace name 'SPListItem' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>  The type or
>   namespace name 'SPWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Under the references section I have:

- FPSRVUTL
- FPWEC
- Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client
- Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client.Intl
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq

What should be done in order to remove these errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPSite` lives in Microsoft.SharePoint (`Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`). All of the failures beyond that are part of the cascade of a missing reference. You should also check which .NET Framework you're running. Most development is done under 4.0 at the moment (not client profile)

Comment: Thanks  Graham. I am not able to find Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll on my machine. Also upon some reading I came across sharepoint client object model. The sharepoint site server is not on my local machine , so in this case should i be using client object model to add items to list ?Also what should be the target framework ?

Comment: You should. Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll is for accessing the server side objects. If you're doing CSOM, you should be using things like JavaScript, jQuery, Angular, etc against the server's API's  and getting back a JSON or XML object (whatever your need).

Comment: Thanks Graham.I have written some code and now I am able to add items to the list using  Client object model.

Answer (score 2):

As Graham said you need to add the assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` into your references in order to use it. You can find this DLL on the SharePoint server that you're working with:

On **SharePoint 2013** it lives at:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI
```

And on **SharePoint 2010** it can be found at:

C`:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI`

Comment: Thanks codingo , as commented above i think i am not clear about what should be used, client object model or server object model in my case. Could you please suggest me the right path?

Comment: @user3436156 The code  that you're using above is the server object model. You want Microsoft.SharePoint.dll (the exact name)

Comment: @user3436156  To determine if you should use Client Object Model or Server-side Object Model,  you should ask yourself 'where my code will be executed'. If your program will run on the server, you can use server-side object model. If it will be used from another machine, you should use client-object model.